# 2 Treatments, comparison of proportions. Z test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, z-test

My design is the following: two treatments, T1 and T2. Population is divided in 4 age brackets, and the absolute numbers of enrolled subjects are:

| Age | Treat1 | Treat2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-39 | 1387907 | 12196048 |
| 40-59 | 876762 | 14314721 |
| 60-79 | 295045 | 11928111 |
| 80plus | 93709 | 4233887 |

The outcome. i.e. subjects showing a certain effect, are:

| Age | Treat1 | Treat2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-39 | 31 | 90 |
| 40-59 | 32 | 219 |
| 60-79 | 49 | 737 |
| 80plus | 33 | 991 |

Now, I'd like to see if there is a significant difference between Treat1 and Treat2, given this outcome.
My idea was to perform a 2 sample z-test for proportions for **each** age group. E.g., for **12-39**:
**p1** = 31/1387907 = 0.000022 
**N1** = 1387907

**p2** = 90/12196048 = 0.000007
**N2** = 12196048

Result of two tailed z-test for two proportions:
z = 5.7 
p-val < 0.0001 
**So this looks significant**.

By repeating this for all the age groups, I get that they *are all significantly different*.
Now, is this the correct way to test this data?
If so, next question:
why is it that, when I pool all the subjects together (disregarding the age groups) and perform a z-test, it comes out non-significant? E.g.

**p1** = (31+32+49+33)/(1387907+876762+295045+93709) = 0.000055 
**N1** = 2653423

**p2** = (90+219+737+991)/(12196048+14314721+11928111+4233887) = 0.000048 
**N2** = 42672767

Result of two-tailed z-test for two proportions: 
z = 1.6 
p-val = 0.1118

Is this normal, even if it looks a little counterintuitive to me?

Thanks for helping a total rookie :)

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with very small proportions, so detecting an effect requires relevant sample size. For the last age group (80+), the test significant is if $\alpha = 0.05$ but not if $\alpha = 0.01$. `prop.test` returns a p-value of 0.02.

If we run `power.prop.test()` to determine the sample size required for your last test (total) (indicative power of 0.8):

```
power.prop.test(p1=0.000055, p2=0.000048, power=0.8, alternative="two.sided")
```

The command returns that $n$ should be equal to 16,497,815 in each group which is not the case for `Treat1`.

For the sake of the exercise and to illustrate the impact of the sample size on your test, if you multiply both $x_1$ and $n_1$ (`Treat1`) by 10 in the last age group 80+ (and therefore holding the same proportion), the result of the test for all age groups (total) will become significant.

So, you are doing the right test and it returns the correct result. Your experiment returns low proportions so you might want to keep an eye on  power.